# Load / Render multiple canvases in a single component with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex, babylonjs

I am new to both vuejs & babylonjs.I am trying to render multiple Babylon canvases on the same vue component based on the **version** in the **questionTypeInputs**. However I am getting the variable **canvas** as **undefined**. Also I am using vuex for state management.
I have the following code:

```
<template>
  <canvas
    v-for="(questionTypeInput, index) in questionTypeInputs"
    :key="index"
  ></canvas>
</template>
```

The mounted hook:

```
  mounted() {
try {
  this.questionTypeInputs = store.state.questionTypeInputs;
  const canvases = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
  if (this.questionTypeInputs.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.questionTypeInputs.length; i++) {
      const canvas = canvases[i];
      const questionTypeInput = this.questionTypeInputs[i];
      this.getQuestionObject(questionTypeInput["version"]).then(
        (response) => {
          new Addition(canvas, response);
        }
      );
    }
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
},
```

The questionTypeInputs looks something like:

```
[
{
    "category": "Cat1",
    "version": "1"
},
{
    "category": "Cat2",
    "version": "1"
}
]
```

Is there any better way to achieve this or what needs to be improved in the above code.